# jQuery UI Draggable: Ignore dragging that is dropped in same/initial position

Tags: jquery-ui, draggable, jquery-ui-draggable

I have set up a a number of divs to be "droppable", and some other divs (which are placed inside the droppable divs) to be "draggable".

Here is my code:

```
<script>

function handleDrop (event, ui) {
   var myDiv = document.getElementById("messages");
   var theDrop = $(this);
   var theDrag = ui.draggable;
   myDiv.innerHTML = myDiv.innerHTML + "<br>Dropped [" + theDrag.text() + "] with id = [" +  theDrag.attr("id") + "] in [" + theDrop.attr("id") + "]";

}


  $(function() {

      $( ".item" ).draggable( { tolerance: "fit", revert: "invalid", revertDuration: 150 } );
      $( ".column" ).droppable({ drop: handleDrop });

  });

</script>
```

This works fine, but my question is how can I modify the handleDrop function to detect whether or not the element which the draggable was dropped into is the same as the element where it was when the dragging began? In other words, **how to detect if the dragging started and ended inside the same droppable div ?** (My goal being to ignore such "non-events".)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could deduce the source and target droppable containers using this code:

```
  $( ".column" ).droppable({ 
    drop: function(event, ui) {
        console.log(event.target.id);
        console.log(ui.draggable[0].parentElement.id);

        var target = event.target.id;
        var source = ui.draggable[0].parentElement.id;
        if(target === source)
            alert('Same droppable container');
    }
  });
```

BTW, it is only tested on IE9 and Chrome, sometimes FF has different method to retrieve event parameters.

**EDIT**

Here is a fiddle to explain my last comment http://jsfiddle.net/Bouillou/QvRjL/100/ 
http://jsfiddle.net/Bouillou/QvRjL/100/

Comment: This works on the initial drag/drop, but does not "reset" and shows the alert message if I then drag the same item back to the first area (ie. the "source" variable still points to the original source, not the latest one) ?

Comment: So, save the first container as attribute of your object and retrieve for checking in the callbak like $('#'+ui.draggable[0].id).attr('first-containner')